# How do I use dictionary to represent rows and columns in a multidimensional list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, multidimensional-array

I know how to use dictionary to (A, B, C) represent its rows in a list, but how do I do it in a multidimensional list?

This is what I have got so far

```
string = 'abcjdi'

row1 = string[0:2]
row2 = string[2:4]
row3 = string[4:6]

find = {'A':row1, 'B':row2, 'C':row3}
matrix = [row1, row2, row3]

for i in range(0,3):
    print(matrix[i])

print(find['C'][1])
```

instead of find['C'][1], I want to do find['C']['B'] that shares the same result

Thanks

Comment: Trying to do `find['C']['B']` is a referencing dict in a dict

Comment: Then you will need to make the "rows" dicts as well.

Comment: What would be your expected output of find['C']['B'] ?

Comment: Same as find['C'][1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use letters as an index, than you need to use a dictionary. In this case, you would have a dictionary of a dictionary.

```
string = 'abcjdi'

row_a = {'A': string[0:1], 'B': string[1:2]}
row_b = {'A': string[2:3], 'B': string[3:4]}
row_c = {'A': string[4:5], 'B': string[5:6]}

find = {'A':row_a, 'B':row_b, 'C':row_c}
matrix = [row_a, row_b, row_c]

for d in matrix:
    print(d['A'] + ', ' + d['B'])

print(find['C']['B'])
```